# PowerBI Embedded export function not working

Tags: javascript, powerbi-embedded

I´m using PowerBI Embedded [sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples)  (app owns data)

And my export function works sometimes and sometimes not.. There is no way of trouble shooting the issue as it starts working after couple of minutes even if I dont do anything.

My export function:

```
function exp() {
        report.getPages()
            .then(function (pages) {
                pages[0].getVisuals().then(visuals => {
                    console.log(visuals.length);
                    if (visuals.length >= 5) {
                        visuals[4].exportData(1, 1000)
                            .then(data => {
                                console.log('exportFunction');
                            })
                            .catch(function (errors) {
                                console.log('export error');
                                console.log(errors);
                            });
                    } else {
                        console.log("Error getting visual data");
                    }
                });
            });
    }
```

this code gives me error on line : visuals[4].exportData(1, 1000)  and gives me these errors (Sometimes):

Error:

```
reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:646 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Underlying' of undefined
    at r.<anonymous> (reportembed.bundle.min.js:22)
    at a (reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16)
    at Object.next (reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16)
    at n (reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16)
    at reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:659
    at m.$digest (reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:670)
    at reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:673
    at e (reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:570)
    at reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:573
    at t.invokeTask (reportEmbed.min.js:1
```

Error:

```
reportEmbed.min.js:1 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'Underlying' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Underlying' of undefined
    at r.<anonymous> (reportembed.bundle.min.js:22)
    at a (reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16)
    at Object.next (reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16)
    at n (reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16)
    at reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:659
    at m.$digest (reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:670)
    at reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:673
    at e (reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:570)
    at reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:573
    at t.invokeTask (reportEmbed.min.js:1) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Underlying' of undefined
    at r.<anonymous> (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.4898.154/scripts/reportembed.bundle.min.js:22:454)
    at a (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.4898.154/scripts/reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16:27283)
    at Object.next (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.4898.154/scripts/reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16:26618)
    at n (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.4898.154/scripts/reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16:26350)
    at https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.4898.154/scripts/reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:659:168
    at m.$digest (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.4898.154/scripts/reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:670:130)
    at https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.4898.154/scripts/reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:673:157
    at e (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.4898.154/scripts/reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:570:449)
    at https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.4898.154/scripts/reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:573:300
    at t.invokeTask (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.4898.154/scripts/reportEmbed.min.js:1:376613)
```

Any idea of what is happening?

I have PowerBI.Javascript V2.5.0 and PowerBI.Api v2.0.11

Comment: This looks like a product bug. Will probably be fixed in a week or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a recent bug in the product.
And recently deployed a fix for it.

See [powerbi js export summarized data Error: Cannot read property 'Underlying' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716609/powerbi-js-export-summarized-data-error-cannot-read-property-underlying-of-un) for details, as this is the same issue reported.