# powerbi js export summarized data Error: Cannot read property 'Underlying' of undefined

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

i am trying to use exportData(summarized) of powerbi.js and getting the following error.

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Underlying' of undefined
>     at r.<anonymous> (reportembed.bundle.min.js:22)
>      at a (reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16)
>      at Object.next (reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16)
>      at n (reportembed.common.bundle.min.js:16)
>      at reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:659
>      at m.$digest (reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:670)
>      at reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:673
>      at e (reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:570)
>      at reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:573
>      at t.invokeTask (reportEmbed.min.js:1)`

I tried to run the sample in this link (https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#).I see the same error here aswell

[image]

Not sure if i am missing something on this. Can anyone from the powerbi js team help on this.

powerbi js version i am using is 2.5.0

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this was a bug with the Power BI Embedded product.
This has been fixed in recent deployments.